# How can I ensure that a lost update does not occur in my code?

Tags: mysql, database

I just want to simply know what code to write in my procedure to ensure that no lost updates can occur. 
Here's my code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdBal (vcust3 number, vcust7 number) AS
BEGIN
update customer set balance = balance + 100 where custid = vcust3;
update customer set balance = balance - 100 where custid = vcust7;
END;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lost update"?

Comment: If you mean you want a guarantee of atomicity, that is: that either both `UPDATE` statements will be applied or neither will be applied, then wrap it in a `TRANSACTION`: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Transaction and rollback.